# Issues with the subtraction syntax in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

So far i have most of the code written out but the biggest difficulty I am having is that of the output for the inputs brought in by the user. It seems to gather all the data from each one of the strings and then outputting them. I want them to individually output them and show the end result of the subtraction of the credits completed and the credits required. Would appreciate any help that you guys could give and lead me in the write direction of my code.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA 
studentName         DWORD   ?
degreeName              DWORD   ?
creditsCompleted        DWORD   ?
creditsNeeded           DWORD   ?

prompt1 BYTE    "Enter your Name:", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter your Degree Name:", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "Enter the number of Credits Completed:", 0
prompt4 BYTE    "Enter the number of Credits Required:", 0
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)

resultLbl BYTE  "The Credits left to complete are:", 0
sum     BYTE    40 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    input   prompt1, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters
    atod    string          ; convert to integer
    mov     studentName, ebx    ; store in memory

    input   prompt2, string, 40      ; repeat for second number
    atod    string
    mov     degreeName, ecx

    input   prompt3, string, 40
    atod    string 
    mov     creditsCompleted,edx

    input   prompt4, string, 40
    atod    string 
    mov     creditsNeeded,eax


    mov     eax, creditsNeeded     
    sub     eax, creditsCompleted    
    dtoa    sum, eax        
    output  resultLbl, sum  

_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

Cant figure out how the number that i am outputting is not actually subtracting. The number is either going way high or way low.

Comment: I guess `mov     creditsCompleted,edx` should be `mov     creditsCompleted,eax`, because the return value of `atod` is most likely returned in `EAX`.

Comment: This code uses 32-bit registers and thus can't work in emu8086 (which emulates an original 8086, 16-bit only).

Comment: I didn't know what other tags I should use with it. But thank you for letting me know that, I actually had no idea. Are you able to adjust tags for already asked questions?